# Adding a Worker Dyno Process to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, worker, heroku-postgres

I'm brand new to Heroku and I'm starting to get H13 errors (timeout) with my app when I upload big files that take more than 30 seconds to process.

So, I'm trying to use worker dynos by following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq

So far I have installed rq, created worker.py (copied from the guide), and added import code for rq and worker.

I have one python file that looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
  # Code that uploads file and adds it to postgresql table
  return render_template('reports.html', reports=reports)

@app.route('/reports/<string:report_uuid>')
def report(report_uuid):
  # Code that creates a report based on the sql table
  return render_template('report.html', data=data)
```

My question is where do I add this line from the guide:

```
result = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://heroku.com')
```

I don't think I understand what is calling the python functions. Does the @app.route('/') mean that when page '/' is visited function main() should run? So would I declare the functions somewhere else and then add a line like:

```
def upload():
  # Code that uploads file and adds it to postgresql table
  return render_template('reports.html', reports=reports)  

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
 q.enque(upload)
```